# Error in configuring opencv

Tags: java, opencv

After configuring opencv i get the following error

> Created dir:
>   C:\Users\User\Documents\GitHub\Linguist\build\web\WEB-INF\classes
>   Created dir:
>   C:\Users\User\Documents\GitHub\Linguist\build\web\META-INF Copying 1
>   file to C:\Users\User\Documents\GitHub\Linguist\build\web\META-INF
>   Copying 86 files to C:\Users\User\Documents\GitHub\Linguist\build\web
>   library-inclusion-in-archive: Copying 1 file to
>   C:\Users\User\Documents\GitHub\Linguist\build\web\WEB-INF\lib Copying
>   1 file to
>   C:\Users\User\Documents\GitHub\Linguist\build\web\WEB-INF\lib Copying
>   1 file to
>   C:\Users\User\Documents\GitHub\Linguist\build\web\WEB-INF\lib
>   **C:\Users\User\Documents\GitHub\Linguist\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1039:
>   Warning: Could not find file
>   C:\Users\User\Documents\GitHub\Linguist\${libs.OpenCV-300.classpath}
>   to copy**.
>   BUILD FAILED (total time: 1 second)

Please help me to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

It's due to missing of the libraries that I have previously added to the project. Right click the project and go to properties. Then select Library. there You can see the missing libraries. If you waant you can remove those libraries or else you can add them again. This will help to overcome the above mentioned error